# Function that takes a string and "filters out" all the non digit characters and all but the first dot in C?

Tags: c, string, function, digits

For example:   Say that the string is "90.%7."
               The function would filter out the  % and the second dot.
               The function would thus return "90.7"
               I'm flexible as to how it would return it.

Everything i have done so far hasn't worked. Sad Face.

Thanks.

Edit: I figured out how to do it.

Comment: There are already solutions to this problem available. Maybe you search for those and maybe you show what hasn't worked so we can help you with that.

Comment: What *have* you done so far?

Comment: `Everything i have done so far hasn't worked.` Post it here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  More urgently, you should show an MCVE ([MCVE]) that's your best effort so far.  We'll help you fix problems with an honest attempt to solve the problem; we won't generally write the code for you.

Comment: I figured out how to do it. In my  previous attempt, i made basic mistake. I forgot that in C the else statement gets "attached" the the previous if statement. I can post the solution if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code

```
void filter(const char * input, char * output)
{
    int length = strlen(input);
    int dot_was_seen = 0;
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    for( i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
    {
        if(input[i] >= 0x30 && input[i] <= 0x39)
            output[j++] = input[i];
        else if(!dot_was_seen && input[i] == 0x2E)
        {
            output[j++] = input[i]; 
            dot_was_seen = 1;
        }
    }
    output[j] = 0;
}

int main()
{
    char input[] = "90.%7.";
    char output[32];

    filter(input, output);

    printf(output);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why use obscure hex instead of clearer `'0'` .. `'9'` and `'.'`?  Or even consider using `isdigit()` from `<ctypes.h>`?  Also, you could forgo `strlen()` and `length`; simply test `input[i] != '\0'` in the `for` loop condition.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, tnx will consider an edit as soon as I get back to my PC